# Can`t login with seeded database configuration using asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a problem with login, even though i see the tables are filled with my seeded user info from Configuration.cs:

```
protected override void Seed(www.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Roles.Any(x => x.Name == "admin"))
            {
                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
                var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
                var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" };
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }

            if (!context.Users.Any(x => x.UserName == "admin" && x.Email == "admin@admin.com"))
            {
                var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin", Email = "admin@admin.com" };
                var hasher = new PasswordHasher();
                userManager.Create(user, "MySecret5");
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
            }
        }
```

and when i try to login i get error "Invalid login attempt".
What am i missing?

EDIT:
Im in the process of learning all stuff about asp.net so im pretty big noob now :( so i found this example to be working for me, and if anyone else needs it here it is:

```
protected override void Seed(www.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

            if (!context.Users.Any(x => x.UserName == "admin@v.com"))
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin@v.com", Email = "admin@v.com" };
                userManager.Create(user, "Password5%");
                context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" });
                context.SaveChanges();
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
            }
        }
```

And thanks for all your help and time.

Comment: What is the `IdentityResult` from the initial `userManager.Create(user, "MySecret5");` call?  Also, where is this run from?  I can imagine a scenario where the migration is run from a local machine, which would use the local machines `MachineKey` to hash the password, compared to performing the logon on the Web Server (which would use a different `MachineKey`).

Comment: Where to check the IdentityResult?

Comment: `var result = userManager.Create(user, "MySecret5");`.  IdentityResult has the following definition: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: I dont know how/where to check that, but if you mean this part userManager.Create(user, "MySecret5"); when i run the application in debug mode it never gets to there,  the tracing stops to this part :
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);  and the result is failure

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, but in this line `var hasher = new PasswordHasher();` you are creating a `hasher` variable and then not using it for anything. It seems like somewhere here you should be hashing the user's password when you are seeding the data, but you are not.

Comment: @NightOwl888 i have removed that part an hour ago, and i still cant login so its not that, sadly.

Comment: @john - But where are you adding the password? I wouldn't expect you to be able to login if the seeded data has no password.

Comment: @NightOwl888 well isnt this line adding the password:
userManager.Create(user, "MySecret5"); ???

Comment: Check your IdentityConfig and make sure UserLockoutEnabledByDefault is not set to true. If it is, add userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(user.Id, false); Also check your PasswordValidator settings to make sure your password meets those criteria (RequireNonLetterOrDigit).

Comment: @SteveGreene about password validation i always change that to not bother me to
RequiredLength = 3,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = false,
                RequireLowercase = false,
                RequireUppercase = false,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked flawlessly for me.

```
protected override void Seed(www.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

            if (!context.Users.Any(x => x.UserName == "admin@v.com"))
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin@v.com", Email = "admin@v.com" };
                userManager.Create(user, "Password5%");
                context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" });
                context.SaveChanges();
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the problem with logging in with seeded users is associated with MVC inaccuracy, look at:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Emali, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

if we seed this user:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "SomeName", Email = "admin@v.com" };
```

result will be == **false**, but if we change **model.Emali** in result to **model.UserName** then login end with success - of course now when we log in, we must give the UserName e.g:

UserName: SomeName;

Passwort: Password5%;